# sudo command not found

Tags: debian, sudo, docker

I got my init.sh file for installing seafile. When calling:

```
if  [ ! -f /config/init_completed ]; then
    ...
else
  # start seafile
  sudo bash ${INSTALLPATH}seafile.sh start
  sudo bash ${INSTALLPATH}seahub.sh start
  # keep seafile running in foreground to prevent docker container shutting down
  while true; do
    sudo tail -f /opt/seafile/logs/seafile.log
    sleep 10
  done

fi
```

I got the error: `/scripts/init.sh: line 44: sudo: command not found`

Install Path is a environmental Variable set in the Dockerfile:

```
ENV SEAFILE_VERSION seafile-server-6.3.4
ENV INSTALLPATH /opt/seafile/${SEAFILE_VERSION}/
```

`whoami` output is root

Without the sudo command the error is (guess it's cause I don't have permissions without sudo):

```
bash: /opt/seafile/seafile-server-6.3.4/seafile.sh: No such file or 
directory
```

Comment: @JeffSchaller If I put an `sudo ls -l ${INSTALLPATH}seafile.sh` before (in the else condition) it reports with the same error. If I run it without sudo the second error occurs.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the if condition?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I'm not logged in as root, but when adding an "whoami" it tells me "root"

Comment: @JeffSchaller I also did that. It's telling: `ls: cannot access '/opt/seafile/seafile-server-6.3.4/seafile.sh': No such file or directory
`

Comment: That's a great edit to your post, then; it narrows the problem down.  I suspect one of your variables has a non-printing whitespace character in it (carriage return, likely)

Comment: @JeffSchaller So, checking these didn't give any helpfull information, also rewriting all the variables by hand didn't solve it.

Comment: Every indication is that the file you're expecting to execute *isn't there*; are you *sure* it is?

Comment: `cd /opt/seafile/seafile-server-6.3.4/` is giving the correct output, yes.

Also I can start the script manually by using:
`sudo bash ${INSTALLPATH}seafile.sh start`

It's just not working in the init.sh

Answer (score 2):

Sudo is not installed in Debian by default. You can install it with the command
`apt-get install sudo`
Or you can edit the script, remove the **sudo** references and run it as root.

The second error

> bash: /opt/seafile/seafile-server-6.3.4/seafile.sh: No such file or 
>   directory

Is bash saying that there is no file with the name **seafile.sh** in the **/opt/seafile/seafile-server-6.3.4/** directory. Check both names (maybe you have to extract some file before, or maybe the seafile version is different from 6.3.4) and try again.

Comment: I already installed "sudo" by doing so.
It works fine in every other command.

The file exists and also is spelled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding sudo to `ENTRYPOINT sudo bash /scripts/init.sh`.